# is this possible in java or any other programming language

Tags: java, programming-languages

```
public abstract class Master
{
    public void printForAllMethodsInSubClass()
    {
        System.out.println ("Printing before subclass method executes");
            System.out.println ("Parameters for subclass method were: ....");
    }
}

public class Owner extends Master {
    public void printSomething () {
        System.out.println ("This printed from Owner");
    }

    public int returnSomeCals ()
    {
        return 5+5;
    }
}
```

Without messing with methods of subclass...is it possible to execute `printForAllMethodsInSubClass()` before the method of a subclass gets executed?

**update:**

Using AspectJ/Ruby/Python...etc
Would it also be possible to print the parameters? Above code formatted below:

```
public abstract class Master
{
    public void printForAllMethodsInSubClass()
    {
        System.out.println ("Printing before subclass method executes");

    }
}

public class Owner extends Master {
    public void printSomething (String something) {
        System.out.println (something + " printed from Owner");
    }

    public int returnSomeCals (int x, int y)
    {
        return x+y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to know: in Struts there's an interface (http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/Preparable.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[AspectJ](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/) can provide this functionality for you, but it's a separate compilation step and some extra libraries involved.

```
public aspect ServerLogger {
    pointcut printSomething ();

    before(): printSomething()
    {
            (Master)(thisJoinPointStaticPart.getTarget()).printForAlMethodsInSubClass();
    }
}
```

The Eclipse Project provides a great implementation of AspectJ that integrates nicely with Eclipse and Maven.  There's a boatload of great documentation available for it, and a lot of really good material for it here on StackOverflow.

[update]

To access parameter info, you can use the

```
thisJoinPoint.getSignature();
```

method to access information about the function being called if the returned Object is an instance of [MethodSignature](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/runtime-api/index.html), you can use Signature.getParameterNames() to access the parameters to the function being called. You'd have to use a bit of reflection to actually get at the values, I think - AspectJ doesn't seem to handle this for you.  I'd have to actually do some experimentation to get some working code for you.

Comment: I am not familiar with AspectJ at all. can you provide any particular links that would explain this?

Comment: thanks. will have to look at aspectJ. seems like whole other world I was unaware of. one liner question though. Can aspectJ be utilized in J2EE like applications?

Comment: @drake:  absolutely.  You can use AspectJ in any 1.4/1.5+ environment, from standalone AWT/Swing apps, to J2EE.  You find plenty of examples using it from basic servlets all the way to Spring apps.

Comment: @chris thanks. I'm reading up AspectJ in action book now. Question: would it also be able to print out all the parameter values of the subclass method? please see update

Answer (score 2):

To answer the "any other programming language": It's easily possible in Ruby:

```
class Master
  REDEFINED = []
  def printForAllMethodsInSubClass
    puts 'Printing before subclass method executes'
  end

  def self.method_added(meth)
    if self < Master and not Master::REDEFINED.include? meth
      new_name = "MASTER_OVERRIDE_#{meth}".intern
      Master::REDEFINED.push meth, new_name
      alias_method new_name, meth
     define_method(meth) {|*args| printForAllMethodsInSubClass; send(new_name, *args)}
    end
  end
end
```

You could also make a proxy declaration method to use in subclasses:

```
class Master
  def printForAllMethodsInSubClass
    Printing before subclass method executes
  end

  def self.master_method(name)
    define_method(name) {|*args| printForAllMethodsInSubClass; yield *args}
  end
end

class Owner
  master_method(:print_something) do
    puts "This was printed from Owner"
  end
end
```

(This approach would also translate very naturally to Python decorators.)

Comment: Thanks. I was interested in seeing how functional programming languages would do this. Would it be possible to print parameter values as well? please see update

Comment: tried your code http://pastie.org/860085 but it fails and uses massive memory....is my implementation wrong?

Comment: Nope, my mistake. I don't do `method_added` metaprogramming that much, forgot one of its quirks and didn't have time to test. Will fix.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in aspect-oriented programming languages, such as [AspectJ](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/).

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can accomplish this using meta classes, here's a small example. You can probably make it more elegantly but it is just to make the point

```
import types

class PrintMetaClass(type):
  def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
    # for every member in the class
    override = {}
    for attr in attrs:
        member = attrs[attr]
        # if it's a function
        if type(member) == types.FunctionType:
          # we wrap it 
          def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            print 'before any method'
            return member(*args, **kwargs)
          override[attr] = wrapped
    super(PrintMetaClass, cls).__init__(name, bases, attrs)
    for attr in override:
      setattr(cls, attr, override[attr])

class Foo:
    __metaclass__ = PrintMetaClass
    def do_something(self):
        print 2

class Bar(Foo):
    def do_something_else(self):
        print 3
```

In this example, the `PrintMetaClass` gets in the way of the creation of the `Foo` class and any of its subclasses redefining every method to be a wrapper of the original and printing a given message at the beginning. The `Bar` class receives this aspect-like behavior simply by inheriting from `Foo` which defines its `__metaclass__` to be `PrintMetaClass`.

Metaclasess in OOP:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaclass

Metaclasses in python:

- http://www.python.org/doc/essays/metaclasses/
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-pymeta.html

Comment: have not dabbled into python at all. but i will give this a try. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Besides aspect oriented programming have a look at Template Method Pattern, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern.

In short: the parent class have an abstract method, which subclasses have to implement, this abstract method is called by a method in the parent class where put your printouts or whatever necessary statements.